# Get base URL and anything past the .com part with both JavaScript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I am working on a Bookmarking application with PHP, JavaScript, and MySQL/SQLite.

I have a text input filed to enter a bookmark URL which uses AJAX to check the input value on the server to see if the URL already exist in the Bookmarks database.

`http://www.domain.com` would show up as being a duplicate if that exact value `http://www.domain.com` was saved in the database.

If it had a trailing slash `http://www.domain.com/` it would be overlooked and not show up as a duplicate!

So that is simple enough if I make sure to remove trailing slash before saving new records to DB.

What I want to do though is generate 2 URL's from each URL string...

If I have this URL:
    `http://www.domain.com/some-article/page/2

Then I would like to be able to get this part `http://www.domain.com` into a variable and then also get this part `/some-article/page/2` into another variable.

This way I will be able to bookmark many pages of a website but also find out if I have any pages of that website domain bookmarked already.

So I would like to be able to get the base URL from any type of URL string.  Secondly be able to get any value in the URL that is past the `.com` portion.

I know this is some basic stuff but I can not think of the name of these domain sections at the moment and could use help in getting them with both JavaScript and PHP.

Answer (score 3):

PHP has a built-in [parse_url() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), so you can do this:

```
$domain = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST); // Get the full domain eg. www.com
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH); // Get the URL
```

Now I propose that you ignore the schema (http://) so that the same link cannot be submitted twice – as http:// and then as https://. In general, most websites serve the same content over plain and encrypted channels.

And in JavaScript:

```
var parser = document.createElement('a');
parser.href = url; // Your URL here
console.log(parser.hostname); // Your domain
console.log(parser.pathname); // Your path
```

Comment: thanks I completely overlooked all this in both languages!

Answer (score 3):

This is how you do it in JS:

```
var parser = document.createElement('a');
parser.href = "http://example.com:3000/pathname/?search=test#hash";

parser.protocol; // => "http:"
parser.hostname; // => "example.com"
parser.port;     // => "3000"
parser.pathname; // => "/pathname/"
parser.search;   // => "?search=test"
parser.hash;     // => "#hash"
parser.host;     // => "example.com:3000"
```

And use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) for PHP.

Comment: thanks do you know if anything exist in PHP that breaks it down to all these pieces as well?

Comment: n/m I see the PHP doc for parse_url has more options